# Making a custom right-click context menu in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

In pyqt5 I can make a right-click context menu with QMenu but this is too standard for me. I created a nice looking widget with the qt-designer an want to use it as a context menu for specific works. Now I use many eventfilter and mousepressevents to work with it, but I think this is not the right way. Is it possible to use the integrated funktions in pyqt5 to make a custom context menu work?

Comment: Context menu are called by overriding the [`contextMenuEvent()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent) of the widget or by using [`setContextMenuPolicy()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) to `Qt.CustomContextMenu` and connecting to the [`customContextMenuRequested`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) of the widget. Note that Qt uses QActions to properly create actions that are *also* used in menus, so your custom widget should actually support them. This is very important for widgets that already have "embedded" menus (like QTextEdit).

Comment: Also note that QMenu might seem a simple widget, but it actually is very complex and provides *very important* features that users give for granted, like proper screen placement, correct focus handling (which is normally hard to achieve due to the way focus handling works when changes happen as consequence of user events) and proper keyboard navigation/mouse interaction. Long story short, since menus are usually dynamic in contents, it seems a bit strange that you created a compatible and reliable "menu" in Designer, as most of its aspects (including item creation) are almost always dynamic.

Comment: To be honest i did not know that pyqt5 has integrated functions to make that. My context menu just has a few functionalities just for one part in my Gui and should not be a dynamically menu which i can use in different sections. For me it was only important that the menu looks good so i made my own.

Comment: It's nothing specific to Qt (remember, PyQt is only a binding to the Qt toolkit, which is written in C++), it's something that is expected by *any* toolkit that creates context menus on its own. Besides, before doing something that looks good, you must be sure to understand how it would work: while important, appearance cannot have precedence over functionality.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I didn't think about it any further and just got to work. Well, I've done it now and then I took care of the design. now it works as it should.